# How do I find the price of a group at 50 percentile of units in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this :

| Category | Units | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 4 | 3.5 |
| a | 5 | 4.5 |
| a | 3 | 7.8 |
| a | 8 | 11.5 |
| a | 1 | 15.5 |
| b | 5 | 2.1 |
| b | 6 | 4.5 |
| b | 3 | 6.5 |

How do I find the price of the 50th percentile Units?

Comment: Please edit your message and post your current code

Comment: `df["Unit"].describe()` or `df["Unit"].quantile(0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```py
df[df.Unit == df.Unit.quantile(0.5)]['Price']
```

But it won't work most of the times if the data is sparse.
Another suggestion would be rank all the values in the `Unit` column, and select the middle one:

```py
df['rank'] = df['Unit'].rank(method = 'first') # rank values of 'unit' column
df[df['rank'] == len(df)//2] # filter by middle value
```